# What's the file format to move an html bookmark file into Firefox 26

Tags: windows-7, firefox, bookmarks, file-format, html-files

Running Firefox 26.0 under XP, I exported my bookmarks to an Html file, to clean up and then import them to my new computer running Windows 7 64-bit professional.  The file is down to about 2500 url shortcuts and no other content.

What I need now is the exact file format to import this into Firefox 26.0 under Win7. 
How do I represent the folder and subfolder names and their description, and the bookmark description. 
I assume the url shortcuts stays as I now have them. I don't have any tags but how would I do them. 
Also, after a folders with subfolders, how do I indicate the start of a new main folder. 
And what warnings can you give me?
Thanks Al

Comment: Not exactly the answer you may be looking for, but have you tried the sync capability built in to Firefox? It will take care of all of what you are trying to do automatically.

Comment: use a `.json`, you can see what they look like in here `C:\Users\VARIES\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\VAR.IES\bookmarkbackups` (**note:** AppData is usually hidden) then after you finish import it with `import bookmark from HTML...`

Comment: You do this from Firefox bookmarks Library <Ctrl+I+O> » Backups bookmarks, to a **.json** file, that you import in your other profile from the very same place. This is also supported with **html** bookmarks backups starting with Firefox 43: Doest imports tags from html bookmarks. My sources and test: https://www.diigo.com/outliner/85adjv/Bookmarks-made-usable!-Sync%2C-merge-and-more# - Finally do your export, merge :)